# Euclidean space and set $M\cap M^{\bot}$

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

If $M$ is subspace of some Euclidean space $E$ than set $M\cap M^{\bot}$ sometimes is empty, sometimes is not.

I read in book that $M\cap M^{\bot}=\{0\}$ so it can not be sometime empty sometimes not, is this true?

Comment: You are asking if both cases are possible. Which one do you not have an example for? (Which one do you have an example for?)

Comment: I have is book that is always empty, for general not just for one case,

Comment: Could you read my question again? This is not an appropriate answer at all.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have example for nothing just it write like that, sorry my english is not so good

Comment: All right, then here is an idea. Pick any Euclidean space. Then pick any subspace. Check if $M\cap M^\perp$ is trivial or not. I GUARANTEE you that you will have an example for at least one of the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that every subspace of a vector space $V$ contains the null vector, i.e. the intersection of subspaces is never empty.

Now, let $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ be a euclidean space. Note also, that $M\bot M^\bot$, i.e. that $M$ and its orthogonal complement are orthogonal.

To see this, let $m\in M, m'\in M^\bot$. Now, $\langle m,m'\rangle=0$ as

$$M^\bot=\{v\in V\mid\forall m\in M:\langle m,v\rangle =0\}$$

i.e. as $m'\in M^\bot$, it is specifically orthogonal to $m\in M$.

Now, let $v\in M\cap M^\bot$, i.e. as $M\bot M^\bot$, we have $\langle v,v\rangle=0$ by the above as $v$ is in both subspaces and they are orthogonal, i.e. $v=\mathbf0$ by positive definiteness of the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.